# Array of char pointers in C - Distinguishing empty elements

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have an array of char pointers in C with a size of 10.

I am trying to loop through and print each string out. Not all of the elements are populated and I believe this is causing me an error. How do I check if an element is populated.

This is what I have tried. When I run my code I find that the first element is populated and the value is printed but then I get an error.

```
char *errors[10];
ret = doMessages(&h, errors);
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if(errors[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", errors[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code for doMessages().

Comment: What error do you get? Also, how are you allocating the memory for each string in the doMessages function? I say you should use the calloc function to guarantee that if the string is not populated, it will be initialized with 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`errors` is not initialised so the elements can be any value, specifically may not be NULL. Change to:

```
char *errors[10] = { 0 }; /* Initialise all elements to NULL. */
```

Comment: That means your doMessages() is not properly initializing `errors`. Please add the code for that.

Comment: @DanielRose, or only assigning strings to certain elements of `errors`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably only the first element of `errors` is been populated. The rest are garbage values (may be NULL, and may be anything), so your check (`!=NULL`) doesn't really check that an element has populated.

I suggest you to initialize your array before `doMessages`, (something like `char *errors[10]={0};`, and then the check `errors[i]!=NULL` will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You do not explicitly initialize the values in your array to `NULL`, so they contain whatever happened to previously exist in the memory location where your array is stored.

To initialize, use something like

```
char *errors[10] = { 0 };
```

You could also do the same with `memset`:

```
char *errors[10];
memset(errors, 0, sizeof(errors));
```